# How to add page breaks in DITA-OT

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, dita-ot

I'm working on a custom plugin for transforming a DITA bookmap into PDF, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to add page breaks in my XSL Transform.

```
<part href="c_somefile.dita">
    <topichead navtitle="Part subheading">
        <topicref href="t_mainfile.dita" chunk="select-document by-document to-content">
            <topicref href="t_firstpart.dita" />
            <topicref href="t_secondpart.dita" />
            <topicref href="t_thirdpart.dita" />
        </topicref>
...
</part>
```

When the `topicref` are resolved, they bring in task elements, so I added the following in topics.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' part/topic/task ')]">
    <fo:block page-break-after="always" />
</xsl:template>
```

But nothing happens. Even if I try to match only on `task` nothing happens. I want to have a page break after each major task, but not the sub-tasks. I've even tried making a custom processing instruction as outlined in https://blog.oxygenxml.com/topics/pageBreakPlugin.html but it didn't work either. It's been 20 years since I used XSLT and I'm feeling very lost.

EDIT: Today I'm experimenting with setting an `outputclass="page-break-before"` on a `topicref` in my bookmap and the following template in commons.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' page-break-before ')]">
    <fo:block break-before="page" />
</xsl:template>
```

But as expected, it's not doing anything.

Comment: You would first need to identify where/how your `task` elements or the `part` or `topic` elements they are specializations of are processed in the OT. Then basically you have to make sure you override that template with your own that you import as needed. So search the existing sources for any `contains(@class, ' part/topic/task ')`

Comment: Could you share the xml with @class attribute containing ' part/topic/task '?
And could it be that some other match in your xslt has a higher priority?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use outputclass attribute. Add a value to the outputclass for task after which you need a page break i.e.

```
outputclass='nextpage'
```

and then create a template

```
<xsl:template match="task[@outputclass=' nextpage ']">
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="section">
        <xsl:attribute name="page-break-after" select="'always'"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I added that template to one of the existing XSL files, but it doesn't work for me.